# What's the right way to add haml to a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-3

While looking for a way to add haml as the templating engine to my rails app I came upon two distinct ways to do it.

The first one is to just add 'gem "haml-rails"' to the Gemfile.

The second one is to add this code to config/application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :haml
end
```

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the gem because it adds the generators.

Update: The 'haml-rails' gem provides the generators. You'll still need to set the `template_engine` to haml if you want haml templates by default.

Comment: @cdmwebs- Your update is incorrect- if you're using 'haml-rails' it sets the template engine to haml for you automatically

Answer (score 0):

You add your gems into the Gemfile in order to specify external dependencies.

Without adding haml to your Gemfile, Bundler will not know about it and your Haml templates won't render on machines that do not have haml installed.

Just follow the instructions of the documentation... http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#plugin

Or is there a reason to deviate from the recommended way?

Comment: Using haml-rails will include haml since it's a dependency. The haml-rails gem adds the rails generators.